# How to reference a class libraries into other class libraries and web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In my .net project I have 4 class libraries and a web project. Can you please guide me towards the correct way to add a reference of one class library to another class library?

In every project inside `Bin` there are two folders:

```
Debug
Release
```

I have tried selecting an assembly reference form `Bin/Debug/`, but every time I clear my project, all references are lost and I have to build projects one by one, which is a sort of pain. Also, it looks like when I build projects in Release mode these references will not work again.

My way of referring is probably not correct. Can you please guide me towards the best way to use references? Is there any way that I can be saved from these issues?

Comment: If there is a "dll reference chain", then all the dlls in that chain should be added to target assembly.

Comment: gentalmen whyn down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bin and release folders are there for building the project, thus when cleaning the solution those will be deleted (usually).

We usually add a folder, and place referenced assemblies in this folder, the folder forms part of your main solution structure, so it may be checked into source control.

Comment: thanks, but I m still working on project, this way every time I will need to manually copy latest assamblies into that folder ? Is it how you are refering it to work ?

Comment: What assemblies are these, the projects you are currently working on i.e. that forms part of your current solution. Or assemblies from other solutions?

Comment: these of assamblies of class libraries of my project like DAL being referenced in business/ service layer and business being referenced in UI.

Comment: Then when adding the reference select solution from the 'Reference Manager' windows, click solution and select the appropriate solution you want a reference too. This copies the new references to that solution every time it builds (Or at least it usually does)

Comment: wonderful looks that is what I was missing. Just to confirm, when I build in "Release", will it automatically get release assemblies or still assamblies built in "Debug" mode ?

Comment: Yes when changing from debug to release all assemblies for the solution will be built as release, visual studio manages that for you.